# The following classes could not be instantiated

Tags: android, android-layout, android-widget, android-xml

I am new to android development and I am trying to import a lib. But I am getting the following error in my XML file:

The following classes could not be instantiated:

```
- com.squareup.timessquare.CalendarPickerView
```

Here is my XML File:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <com.squareup.timessquare.CalendarPickerView
    android:id="@+id/calendar_view"
    android:layout_width="280dp"
    android:layout_height="75dp"
    />
</LinearLayout>
```

Can anybody pls help?

Comment: What is  com.squareup.timessquare.CalendarPickerView?

Comment: receiving the error when you run the app?

Comment: CalenderPickerView is a lib that i am using. I get this error in my xml graphical view. When I try to run it, it force closes